# Is there any way of use asan in gcc 4.7

Tags: gcc, address-sanitizer

According to the address-sanitizer home page it comes only with the gcc 4.8 or above. Isn't there anyway of using it with gcc 4.7?

Comment: Do you think the official homepage is lying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no reliable way (to get ASAN before GCC 4.8). **[ASAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) requires compiler support and is very intimately connected to your particular compiler** (and version, and host and target systems, and specific configuration, etc...)

In other words, **try to compile a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)** (that is, [GCC 5.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) in july 2015; use that since ASAN did progress since 4.8 and you'll get more `-fsanitize=` options in recent versions of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org)) from its [downloaded](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html) source code. See hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101143/841108) & [there](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/). You should try some recent Linux distribution.

<sup>(on Linux or other POSIX systems, you don't need root privileges to configure, compile, and install `gcc-mine-5` in `$HOME/soft/`; you need appropriate `../gcc-5.2/configure` options, notably `--prefix=$HOME/soft --program-suffix=-mine-5`, then add `$HOME/soft/bin/` in your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) then run with `CC=gcc-mine-5` e.g. for `make`)</sup>